# AFNetworking 3.0 multipart request

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:TOKEN]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [manager POST:@"http:xxxxx" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:profileImage name:@"file" fileName:@"profileImage.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    } success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
        completionHandler(responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSData *errorData = error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey];
        NSDictionary *serializedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: errorData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        errorHandler(serializedData);
    }];
```

This method is working fine, but `constructingBodyWithBlock` is deprecated. How can I optimize code to conform **AFNetworking 3.0** standards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`POST:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:progress:success:failure:`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/3.0.4/Classes/AFHTTPSessionManager.html#//api/name/POST:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:progress:success:failure:) rendition (supplying `nil` for `progress` if you don't need it).

You do not need to set the `Accept` and `Content-Type` header types. Those are set by the `AFJSONResponseSerializer` and `AFJSONRequestSerializer`, respectively.

Comment: @ios developer, You can use AFNetworking method from AFNetworking+UIImageView setImageWithUrl